# How to prevent directory traversal when joining paths in node.js?

Tags: web-application, node.js, directory-traversal

I have a node.js webapp in which I need to concatenate two paths in a safe way. The first one (leftmost) is a constant, and the second one (rightmost) is relative to the first one and comes from untrusted user input. The resulting path should be something that is below the first path. So the situation is this:

```
path1 = "public/html";                // Hardcoded path.
path2 = req.query.path;               // Untrusted user input.
result = safePathJoin(path1, path2);  // Result can be e.g. public/html/index.htm,
                                      // but never private/config.xml
```

What I need is the function `safePathJoin()` that is safe against directory traversal attacks. My first naive approach is this:

```
safePathJoin = function(path1, path2) {
    path1 = path.normalize(path1);
    var result = path.join(path1, path2);
    return result.startsWith(path1) ? result : undefined;
}
```

Is this good enough? Is there a standard way to do this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's is one approach I've used in this situation:

1. [`path.normalize()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_path) handles all `.` and `..`, so you can be sure that if either one is present, it will be at the front of the path.
2. Remove any `../../` from the front of your path.

So:

```
var safeSuffix = path.normalize(unsafeSuffix).replace(/^(\.\.(\/|\\|$))+/, '');
var safeJoin = path.join(basePath, safeSuffix);
```

---

**About your approach:** checking the prefix seems like a pretty good idea to me.  There are a couple of problems I see with your implementation:

- You've checked for a prefix without a trailing slash: `../html-other` will resolve to `public/html-other`, which I guess is not what you want.
- You would run into trouble on Windows systems, where `.normalize()` would convert `/` to `\`, meaning *no* paths would work.

When I've done prefix-checking (for slightly different situations), here's what I ended up with:

```
function checkPrefix(prefix, candidate) {
    // .resolve() removes trailing slashes
    var absPrefix = path.resolve(prefix) + path.sep;
    var absCandidate = path.resolve(candidate) + path.sep;
    return absCandidate.substring(0, absPrefix.length) === absPrefix;
}
```

(Yes, I added `path.sep` to both, so that the prefix dir itself passes the test.)

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! Concerning your last example, is there any benefit to using `path.resolve()` to get the absolute path, as opposed to use `path.normalize()` and stay with relative paths?

Comment: `path.normalize()` [keeps trailing slashes](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_path), so you'd need some extra logic for prefix directories of both `public/html` and `public/html/` to work correctly.

Comment: A bit late to the party here, but wouldn't this still be vulnerable to `path/../../../whatever`

Comment: @3ocene: That's the reason we use path.normalise() as step 1.  It cancels any internal `../`, so your example would be converted to `../../whatever` before step 2. :)

Comment: @cloudfeet, that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: This does not deal with the case where unsafePrefix = '..'! Perhaps .replace(/^(\.\.[\/\\])+/, '').replace(/^(\.\.)$/, '') is safer?

Comment: @Brendon - Thanks!  Chnged to `.replace(/^(\.\.(\/|\\|$))+/, '')`, which I think is more succinct.

Comment: I don't know what the situation was when this question was originally answered, but there is [official NodeJS documentation on how to prevent path traversal](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/file-system/security/introduction/#preventing-directory-traversal).

Basically you use `path.join` to create an absolute path and then check if the result starts with your base path. If not: attempted path traversal.

Seems simpler and safer to me.

Comment: For security-relevant regexes, make sure to break them into easily-understandable components, thoroughly commenting the intent behind every component. More importantly, security-relevant regexes shouldn't be trusted without a comprehensive test suite. The fact that even this relatively simple one had a bug is a good reminder of their fickleness.

Comment: @MichaelSandino the link seems to be dead, here is the archive.org link https://web.archive.org/web/20211128060450/https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/file-system/security/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

Given the requirement to receive user input `path` that is a sub-directory of a defined `root` directory and allow user to access (in any way) combined `root` + `path` directory, to me the safest option would be to allow only absolute paths as an input and check that sanitized of any *special directory names* (`.`, `..`) input path equals the original input:

```
// Input

const path1 = "public/html";
const path2 = req.query.path;

// Checkout

const isNotSpecialDirName = part => !(['', '.', '..'].includes(part));

const path2Clean = path2.split(path.sep).filter(isNotSpecialDirName).join(path.sep);

// Output

if (path2Clean !== path2) {
  // Obfuscated with Not Found
  throw new Error('Not Found');
}

const result = path.join(path1, path2Clean);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:
You can just join twice.

```
path1 = "public/html"                // Hardcoded path.
path2 = req.query.path               // Untrusted user input.

const normalized = path.join('/', path2)
const result = path.join(path1, normalized)
```

In the first joining, all `..`, trying to go above the root folder, are ignored because the join method always resolves a parent folder of the root folder is the root folder itself.

So, for example, when `path2` is `../../../test1/test2/../test3`,
`normalized` becomes `/test1/test3`  and `result` will be `public/html/test1/test3`.